# How to edit endpoint settings on Unified AI Platform using Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-ai-platform

I have successfully created an endpoint on Unified Cloud AI Platform and have deployed two `Model`s to it - `Model A` and `Model B` with 20% and 80% of the traffic respectively. Now, on the Cloud Console (the UI) I get an option to **Edit Settings**  and change the traffic split to 30% and 70% respectively and the `Model`s are deployed. However I am unable to figure out how to do this using the Python Client API.

The documentation provided over [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-unified/docs/predictions/deploy-model-api#aiplatform_create_endpoint_sample-python) is inadequate to understand how we could do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for AI Platform Unified does not yet have an example on how to edit the traffic using python. Here is the code for that:

NOTE: Don't forget to update the values for `end_point` (endpoint ID),`project` (project ID), `model_id_1` and `model_id_2` before running the code.

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1


def update_endpoint_traffic(
    end_point: str, 
    project: str, 
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
    timeout: int = 7200,
):
    # The AI Platform services require regional API endpoints.
    client_options = {"api_endpoint": api_endpoint}
    # Initialize client that will be used to create and send requests.
    # This client only needs to be created once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
    client = aiplatform.gapic.EndpointServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    client_model = aiplatform_v1.services.model_service.ModelServiceClient(client_options=client_options)

    deployed_model_id_list = []
    model_id_1 = 'xxxxxxxx' # place your model id here
    model_id_2 = 'xxxxxxxx' # place your model id here
    model_list = [f'projects/{project}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id_1}',f'projects/{project}/locations/{location}/models/{model_id_2}']

    for model in model_list:
        model_request = aiplatform_v1.types.GetModelRequest(name=model)
        model_info = client_model.get_model(request=model_request)
        deployed_models_info = model_info.deployed_models
        deployed_model_id=model_info.deployed_models[0].deployed_model_id
        deployed_model_id_list.append(deployed_model_id)

    traffic_split = {deployed_model_id_list[0]: 60, deployed_model_id_list[1]:40} #update values of 60 and 40 to desired traffic split ex.(30 70)

    name=f'projects/{project}/locations/{location}/endpoints/{end_point}'

    endpoint = aiplatform_v1.types.Endpoint(name=name,traffic_split=traffic_split)
    update_endpoint = aiplatform_v1.types.UpdateEndpointRequest(endpoint=endpoint)
    client.update_endpoint(request=update_endpoint)

update_endpoint_traffic(end_point='your-endpoint-id',project='your-project-id')
```